# how to get metadata Google Maps Static API - specifically the pixel per centimeter resolution

Tags: python, coordinate-system, google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm working with the Google Maps Static API on python. 
My calls are generally looking this way:

```
im_size = "400x400"
zoom = 20
url = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={coord_str}&zoom={zoom}&size={im_size}&maptype=satellite&key={API_KEY}"
```

I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the amount of pixels represent each centimeter in the map? or maybe just get the metadata from the API?

---

EDIT:
I tried [@TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm)'s suggestion and created the following function:

```
def get_meter2pix_res(zoom, latitude):
    return 156543.03 * math.cos(latitude) / (2 ** zoom)
```

(based on `resolution = 156543.03 meters/pixel * cos(latitude) / (2 ^ zoomlevel)`)

Unfortunately it outputs a negative value for Berlin (e.g. - Brandenburg Tor, with latitude=52.51688).

`get_meter2pix_res(20, 52.51688)` returns `-0.094`. 
afaik the problem should be in the cost(latitude) part because its the only option that could make the equation negative. 
I tried to use the absolute value and also to use the longitude (to check if I confuse latitude / longitude) the result is about 10% off from my expectation (expectation from using the "calculate distance on maps.google.com).

---

**SOLUTION:**
The problem was that one needs to translate the latitude to radiants.

```
def get_meter2pix_res(zoom, latitude):
   return 156543.03 * math.cos(math.pi / 180 * latitude) / (2 ** zoom)
```

Comment: It depends on the scale value you define https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#scale_values

Comment: ok, I'm using the default scale. But I still did not find there a way to calculate the pixel to centimeter ratio. To be clear I refer to centimeter/meter in real life, not on screen.

Comment: See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale